# How to resolve npm audit vulnerabilities? Angular fresh project

Tags: angular, npm, package, dependencies, npm-audit

I am creating new angular project with `ng new foobar` - 47 vulnerabilities 
Then I update: `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core` - 39 vulnerabilities 
I don't know how to resolve this issue.

When I run `npm audit` I get two blocks of informations and as a suggested solution I am supposed to install older version of `@angular-devkit/buildangular` which is labeled as breaking change. I assume that breaking change isn't a good solution so what am I supposed to do? Should I just ignore 39 moderate severity vulnerabilities? (I have tried installing what npm is suggesting by running `npm audit fix --force` but this results in a bigger amount of vulnerabilities)

```
ws  5.0.0 - 7.4.5
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1748
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1102.13, which is a breaking change
node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ws
  webpack-dev-server  3.8.0 - 3.11.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of ws
  node_modules/webpack-dev-server
    @angular-devkit/build-angular  >=0.803.0-next.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-preset-env
    Depends on vulnerable versions of resolve-url-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
    node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
```

```
postcss  7.0.0 - 8.2.9
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1693        
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1102.13, which is a breaking change
node_modules/autoprefixer/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/css-blank-pseudo/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/css-has-pseudo/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/css-prefers-color-scheme/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-attribute-case-insensitive/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-color-functional-notation/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-color-gray/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-color-hex-alpha/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-color-mod-function/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-color-rebeccapurple/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-custom-media/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-custom-properties/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-custom-selectors/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-dir-pseudo-class/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-double-position-gradients/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-env-function/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-focus-visible/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-focus-within/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-font-variant/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-gap-properties/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-image-set-function/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-initial/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-lab-function/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-logical/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-media-minmax/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-nesting/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-overflow-shorthand/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-page-break/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-place/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-preset-env/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-pseudo-class-any-link/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-replace-overflow-wrap/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-selector-matches/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-selector-not/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/resolve-url-loader/node_modules/postcss
  autoprefixer  9.0.0 - 9.8.6
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/autoprefixer
  css-blank-pseudo  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-blank-pseudo
  css-has-pseudo  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-has-pseudo
    postcss-preset-env  >=6.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-has-pseudo
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-prefers-color-scheme
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-color-gray
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-double-position-gradients
    node_modules/postcss-preset-env
      @angular-devkit/build-angular  >=0.803.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-preset-env
      Depends on vulnerable versions of resolve-url-loader
      Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
      node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
  css-prefers-color-scheme  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-prefers-color-scheme
  postcss-attribute-case-insensitive  4.0.0 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-attribute-case-insensitive
  postcss-color-functional-notation  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-functional-notation
  postcss-color-gray  >=5.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-gray
  postcss-color-hex-alpha  4.0.0 - 6.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-hex-alpha
  postcss-color-mod-function  >=3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-mod-function
  postcss-color-rebeccapurple  >=4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-rebeccapurple
  postcss-custom-media  7.0.0 - 7.0.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-custom-media
  postcss-custom-properties  8.0.0 - 10.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-custom-properties
  postcss-custom-selectors  5.0.0 - 5.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-custom-selectors
  postcss-dir-pseudo-class  >=5.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-dir-pseudo-class
  postcss-double-position-gradients  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-double-position-gradients
  postcss-env-function  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-env-function
  postcss-focus-visible  >=4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-focus-visible
  postcss-focus-within  >=3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-focus-within
  postcss-font-variant  4.0.0 - 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-font-variant
  postcss-gap-properties  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-gap-properties
  postcss-image-set-function  >=3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-image-set-function
  postcss-initial  3.0.0 - 3.0.4
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-initial
  postcss-lab-function  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-lab-function
  postcss-logical  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-logical
  postcss-media-minmax  4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-media-minmax
  postcss-nesting  7.0.0 - 7.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-nesting
  postcss-overflow-shorthand  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-overflow-shorthand
  postcss-page-break  2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-page-break
  postcss-place  >=4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-place
  postcss-pseudo-class-any-link  >=6.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-pseudo-class-any-link
  postcss-replace-overflow-wrap  3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-replace-overflow-wrap
  postcss-selector-matches  >=4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-selector-matches
  postcss-selector-not  4.0.0 - 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-selector-not
  resolve-url-loader  3.0.0-alpha.1 - 4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/resolve-url-loader
```

Comment: I can confirm I am having the same issues on Angular 12 with @angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.0.5". I am surprised there is not much on it. I would raise a ticket in Angular's github

Comment: And to confirm npm audit fix doesn't do anything

Comment: Further to above run npm audit --production  instead of npm audit. Running production will only show vulnerability that impact your production app whilst later will show errors to your dev environment. Which in my opinion can be ignored. I ran this on my angular app and got 0 for productions vs 10. See https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20564

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `npm audit --production` instead.

Running `npm audit` will show both the dependancies and devDependancies vulnerabilities.

In my opinion whilst dependancies vulnerabilities are critical to resolve, devDependancies are not as it wont be released as part of your app ie its part of the dev environment.

At time of writing for latest angular application, I received 10 vulnerabilities that could not be resolved but all were related to devDependancies. The audit fix wanted me to downgrade `@angular-devkit/buildangular` which made no sense.

However running with production flag i got 0 vulnerabilities.

More details here:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20564

Answer (score 0):

run `npm audit fix`. They won't fix your problems by adding unsafe versions. You can trust this procedure.

Comment: `npm audit fix` doesn't do anything unfortunately. I think the only thing I can do is to ignore it. You probably can update everything manually but that would be a pain and since those vulnerabilities are for dev dependencies I decided to not waste my time on it (unless there is a nice way to do it but I think there isn't)